# Obtaining value of select list each change with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a select list that I would like to display a different image in the same div each time the user changes the select list. Here's what I have so far:

HTML

```
<div id="branches">
    <h3>British Columbia Old Age Pensioners' Organization &mdash; Branches</h3>

    <select id="branch-number" class="form-control">
      <optgroup label="British Columbia">
        <option value="1">Branch 1</option>
        <option value="2">Branch 2</option>
        <option value="http://placehold.it/350x350">Branch 3</option>
        <option value="http://placehold.it/350x450">Branch 4</option>
      </optgroup>
      <optgroup label="Alberta">
        <option value="5">Branch 5</option>
        <option value="6">Branch 6</option>
        ...etc...
    </select>

    <div id="img-window">
      <img id="branch-img" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="img-responsive">
    </div><!-- end img-window -->

</div><!-- end branches -->
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#branch-number').on('change', function () {
        alert('something happened');
        // var branchVal = $('this').val();
        var branchVal = $('option:selected').val();
        switch (branchVal) {
        case 1:
            $('#branch-img').attr('src', 'http://placehold.it/150x150');
            break;
        case 2:
            $('#branch-img').attr('src', 'http://placehold.it/250x250');
            break;
        case 3:
            $('#branch-img').attr('src', 'http://placehold.it/350x350');
            break;
        default:
            $('#branch-img').attr('src', 'http://placehold.it/1450x1450');
        }
    });
});
```

Right now, nothing happens when the user changes the select list. I am trying to do this with an <img> tag instead of CSS so that for increased accessibility of the alt="" attribute.

I'm just starting to get the hang of javascript / jQuery ... any help appreciated.

Here's a fiddle:

> https://jsfiddle.net/r1fcvs7s/4/

edit: syntax should be all good now.

Comment: I think you miss some brackets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML

```
<select id="branch-number" class="form-control">
  <optgroup label="British Columbia">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>Three</option>
    <option>Four</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#branch-number').on('change', function() {

    // var branchVal = $('this').val();
    var branchVal = $('#branch-number').find(':selected').text();

    switch(branchVal) {
        case "1":
        $('#branch-img').attr('src', 'http://placehold.it/350x350/9d9999/000000&text=Abbotsford+Branch');
        break;
        case "2":
        $('#branch-img').attr('src', 'http://placehold.it/250x250/9d9999/000000&text=Chilliwack+Branch');
        break;
        case "Three":
        $('#branch-img').attr('src', 'http://placehold.it/150x150/9d9999/000000&text=Mission+Branch');
        break;
        case "Four":
        $('#branch-img').attr('src', 'http://placehold.it/350x350/9d9999/000000&text=Vancouver+Branch');
        break;
    }

  });

});
```

Had to use the .find(:selected).text(); method instead of the .val(); method. This is because the value attribute is only used for  forms and other things but, not  boxes.

Answer (score 1):

Your `case` syntax is wrong. It should be:

```
switch(branchVal) {
    case 1:
        $('#branch-img').attr('src', 'http://placehold.it/150x150');
        break;
    case 2:
        $('#branch-img').attr('src', 'http://placehold.it/450x450');
        break;
}
```

The `:` comes *after* the value, not before. And you need `break` between the cases unless you want to fall through into the next case (which you obviously don't in this code).

You should have gotten a syntax error in the Javascript console. How did you miss that?

BTW, to get the value of the `<select>`, you can use `$(this).val()`. You don't need to access `option:selected`.

Comment: sorry, I knew that.. i just made a fiddle and realized that i left it like that when i was testing random stuff. i will edit. Ty

Comment: You still have the `:` in the wrong place after the edit. So did you have that right or wrong?

Comment: OH man.... my editor didn't tell me that ... thank you .. i've been doing c++ as well.. getting my syntax's mixed now...

http://2.ii.gl/Jl1VbmbZs.png   ... brackets FTL?

Comment: The syntax is the same in JS as C and C++. None of them use `case: 1`.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. Pretty big derp on my part. I corrected it and it's still not working.

Comment: I just went to the jsfiddle, it has the incorrect syntax. You're making it really difficult to help you.